# Salesforce Apex Map Using sObject (containing duplicate data) as Key

Tags: dictionary, salesforce, apex

```
Map<obj, Integer> myMap = new Map<obj, Integer>;

myObj1 = new obj(value = "a");
myObj2 = new obj(value = "b");
myObj3 = new obj(value = "a");

myMap.put(myObj1, 1);
myMap.put(myObj2, 2);
myMap.put(myObj3, 3);

//myMap.size() returns a value of 2, but I want three distinct entries
```

So, I know why the above is happening, what I want to know is how best to deal with it.

I want to create a map which is keyed using an sObject (a custom object in my app). The problem is that the test for map key uniqueness is on the value of fields of an object and not its location in memory or some other Id.

I would very much like to avoid saving the records and retrieving Ids to use for uniqueness. Any other suggestions on how to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

If two objects return the same hashCode they considered to be the same key.
It is recommended to use immutable objects such as strings for keys in map as if you change your sobjects later it might break the map. Using ids is one good option any other unique field will do.